# Root password not in use in thunar when a user is in sudo group?

Tags: sudo, group

I am just asking for a confirmation here since I'm not really sure how it works

So, I have Debian Stretch on my home machine, I was the sole user so I had a normal user account and used `su -` when I had to use administrative commands. I also use the `root` password to mount my other partitions in the GUI, such as the partition where my music is stored.

My cousin moved in with me and since he wants to learn how to use linux, I created an account for him and added him to the `sudo` group, to allow him to mount the media partition as well (we kinda like the same kind of music), but since then, when I want to mount the partition from my account, it looks like I have to use his password now, not the root password anymore.

So, I wanted to ask if this is a normal behavior (in which case, I just have to add my account to the `sudo` group as well) or if there was something I was doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

In case you want to ask, I like the behavior of not mounting my other partitions by default. And I also like to not have my own account completely separated from administrative tasks as using sudo commands kinda tricks me sometimes.

**Edit**
It looks like my question needs clarification

I can use `su -` in the terminal when I want to switch to `root` for my admin commands, but I was used to mount my other partitions using *thunar* who used to ask me for the `root` password, but now, when I want to mount my partitions, still using *thunar*, now, it prompts me my cousin's password instead of the `root` password.

Comment: Being asked someone else's password when running `su` is not normal. Perhaps your cousin changed the root password? Please add the exact command which works with another user's password.

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l` run as the relevant user, please.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I mean, when using `su -` in the terminal, it works, but when I want to mount my partition from the file manager, it asks for his password... maybe I need to change the title of the question

Comment: @gl_prout And the name of this GUI you're using is?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev well, it's xfce's default file manager, thunar, I kinda forgot its name

Comment: `su` asks for password of the user that you are changing to (by default root). `sudo` asks for the password of the user that you currently are. Note with `sudo` you can also configure it to allow only a limited set of command for a user, e.g. `mount my-media …` (you don't have to give away root). And if I remember correct, mount supports being able to add an entry to `/etc/fstab` that is not auto-mounted, but can be mounted by any user.

Comment: You talk about `su` and `sudo` which are very different, and also you dont talk about the type of partition / server mount your using is it SMB, NFS, FTP, WEBDAV. Who is the owner of those files ?

Comment: @Kiwy it's just my sdb, my secondary hard drive, where I store my music, pictures and videos, whenever completely downloaded or created from my debian or my windows

Comment: @gl_prout what is the partition format ? to whom the files belong to ? Why not just adding a line /etc/fstab to automount this partition ?

Comment: @Kiwy it's NTFS - the files are mine but no-one's system-wise (since I was the only user until my cousin came) - I just don't know yet how to manipulate the fstab and I didn't mind mounting it only when I wanted to

Comment: I wonder if what you're seeing here is a difference in the behavior of `policykit` when there are valid sudoers versus when there no valid sudoers?

Comment: @steeldriver now that is something I'm discovering and can be a hint - and maybe something I could consider looking inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How su and sudo work

- `su` asks for password of the user that you are changing to (by default root).
- `sudo` asks for the password of the user that you currently are.

## Alternatives

- With sudo you can also configure it to allow only a limited set of command for a user, e.g. mount my-media … (you don't have to give away root). Use `sudoedit` to edit the config file. It will check the file before saving. If you don't then you could stop sudo from working. If you don't have root password, or ability to do a live boot into a rescue OS, then you will be locked out.
- If I remember correct, mount supports being able to add an entry to /etc/fstab that is not auto-mounted, but can be mounted by any user

Comment: I will definitely try your second alternative tonight when I get home

Comment: I had to document a little bit on fstab but now I can mount my partitions using my normal user account, thank you

Comment: Note on English usage: to document means to create documentation.